# @ManyToMany using @JoinTable

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

i have the following two entities and one join table:

entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class parent {

@OneToOne(mappedBy="person", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
 private Reader reader;

//more fields and getters and setters and of course @Id.....
}
```

and another entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="READER")
public class Reader{

 @Id
 @Column(name= "READER_ID")
 @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")  
 @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="Person"))  
 private long readerId;

 @OneToOne  
 @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn  
 private Person person;

 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinTable(name = "READER_BOOKS", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="READER_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="BOOK_ID")})
 private List<Books> books;

//more fields and getters and setters
}
```

And i have a join table in the data base which is named "READER_BOOKS" which is consisted with two columns - readerId and bookId - both are a primary key as a pair, and each of the columns is a foreign key to the corresponding table.

A few details:

- I have defined a "ManyToMany" relationship in Reader.java, meaning
  that a reader can have many books ,and books can be reused in other
  readers ( for example another reader can have the same books as other
  readers). Also as you can see the reader id and the person id is the
  same - so i defined a "OneToOne" relationship - which works fine.
- In the books entity class i didn't add a reference or stated any
  relationship because i understood that i don't need to.

### The problem:

When i add a Person and set the reader field with several books, it works and the database is filled with the right values.(a person,reader and join tables are inserted with new rows)

The problem is when i delete the Person instance OR the Reader instance AND ***the books instance is not null***(books are assigned to reader). hibernate is just stuck and not throwing any execption.
***but when the books instance is null*** (didnt assign any books to the reader) the deletion is successfull.

I think that something might be wrong with the "ManyToMany" , because when the join table is empty the deletion is successful.

what is wrong in my implementation?

**Edited: i found out sometimes hibernate gets stuck even if that list is empty, so i think something is also wrong with the "OneToOne" anottation, maybe i missed out something**

Comment: For the many to many could change the annotation like this `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) `

Comment: Tried it, dosent effect anything

Comment: When you add books to the reader they are persisted?  Could add this to Person  on reader attribute for (one to one) @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn

Comment: yes they are persisted. i added the PrimaryKeyJoinColumn and it works,  but now i removed the PrimaryKeyJoinColumn and  for some reason it still works.  how can it be?

Comment: It's strange your mapping seems correct

Comment: ok ill try to play with it and try to reproduce. why did you offer to add "@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn " to the reader reference? i understood that it means that "This annotation specifies a primary key column that is used as a foreign key to join to another table." but this is not the case because in person its just a primary key.

Comment: okay you are right you have to remove it . May be you can try to test only Reader with books without Person to isolate more the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was no problem in my implementation.
i use PL/SQL developer and i didn't notice but it acquired a lock on one of the tables :|.
so when i tried to delete a record, hibernate got stuck and from some reason didn't throw any error.

Any way, the implementation is correct.